# codeigniter pagination : showing DOTS(.) before last page button

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

```
    $pagination_config['per_page'] = 10; 
    $pagination_config['total_rows'] = 100; 
    $pagination_config['anchor_class'] = 'class="page gradient"';
    $pagination_config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a class="page active">';
    $pagination_config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
    $pagination_config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
    $pagination_config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $pagination_config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $pagination_config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $pagination_config['num_links'] = 5;
```

so this works pretty good 
but as you can see i only show 5 page number in my page 
if there's more then 5 pages , i want to show couple of dots before last page button

like

`1 2 3 4 5... Lastpage`

RIGHT NOW IT'S LIKE

`1 2 3 4 5 Lastpage`

how can i do that ?

Comment: will the `...` a link or just 3 dots? If it won't be a link why do not change lib code in `Render the "Last" link` part?

Comment: Your question is not clear: BC your $config['num_links']=5 you suppose to have 1 2 3 4 5 Last and not till 3. Can you explain what you want to achieve or fix your code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pagination_config['per_page'] = 10; 
$pagination_config['total_rows'] = 100; 
$pagination_config['anchor_class'] = 'class="page gradient"';
$pagination_config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a class="page active">';
$pagination_config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
$pagination_config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
$pagination_config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
$pagination_config['first_link'] = 'First';
$pagination_config['num_links'] = 5;

if(ceil($pagination_config['total_rows']/$pagination_config['per_page'])> 5)
    $pagination_config['last_link']    =   '.... Last';
else 
    $pagination_config['last_link']    =   'Last';
```

just check if the page number is greater than 5. simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
$config['last_link'] = '...Lastpage';
```

Comment: not really , cuz i don't want dots to show up , if it doesn't have more than 5 pages